# multiple lines net icon

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, lines

I am doing project on FreeCodeCamp and i want to put two lines next to icon, but one is under the icon, how can i solve it?

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.icon-header {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.icon-text {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" >
<i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"><p><span class="icon-header">Low Prices</span><br><span class="icon-text">Our graphics cards are so cheap and affordable for everyone</span></p></i>
```

Comment: what do you mean by next to icon? Do you want the second line to continue after the first line? It would be good if we can have an image of what you are expecting.

Comment: i want second line under first line ( under .icon-header)

Comment: Your second line is currently under the first line in the snippet you provided. What change do you want then? A screenshot would make things easy for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position for icon

```css
p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 44px;
    position: relative;
}
p i{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 15%;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.icon-header {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.icon-text {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" >
<p><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i> <span class="icon-header">Low Prices</span><span class="icon-text">Our graphics cards are so cheap and affordable for everyone</span></p>
```